# Multithread programming in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

I am getting this error when I am passing browser control to my background tasks which keep track of browser control values. What change do I need in code so I can pass this browser control safely to my background scraper class.

**Error**

```
The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.
```

Here is how I am passing browser control to my background singleton class.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            brwser.Navigate("https://xyz.com");
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
           {
               if (BfScrapper.Instance.CanStart)
                   BfScrapper.Instance.StartTask(brwser);
           });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't repeat tags in titles.

Comment: its not duplicate refreing example is not using Task/Task Factory Class to launch new instance of singleton class

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to start a task which is running an STA thread.

To do so, you will need to use [TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx) (assuming the thread from which you are creating the task is itself an STA thread).

You can pass this to one of the overloads of [TaskFactory.StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd321439.aspx) that accepts a TaskScheduler argument.

For example:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew
(
    () =>
    {
        if (BfScrapper.Instance.CanStart)
            BfScrapper.Instance.StartTask(brwser);
    },
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.None,
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
);
```

I also recommend you google *FromCurrentSynchronizationContext STA*, since this stuff is far from obvious, and has ramifications.

Comment: can you please share snippet of code how to use in this case by passing contorl?

Comment: It works great thanks I wish I could give many points instead of like other people who refereeing to old answers this is what answer I wanted to hear from expert like you. Because this class using Task Factory

Comment: When I first started using Tasks instead of Threads I ran into this problem (it was easy to fix for threads because you can just set the STA state for a thread). It took me quite a while to find out about the FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() thing! But be fair to everyone - they are all trying to help (and I myself often post replies that turn out to be not as helpful as I'd hoped...)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to change something in the passed UI element. The easiest way to do this is like this:

`UIElement.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(/*do stuff here*/);`

I have a handy extension method for this:

```
public static DispatcherOperation DispatcherCall<T>(this T obj, Action action, DispatcherPriority priority) where T : DispatcherObject
        {
            return obj.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(priority, action);
        }
```

the usage would look like this:

```
mLabel.DispatcherCall(() => mLabel.Text = "Test...", DispatcherPriority.Normal);
```

This avoids the rather large cost of always having to switch back and forth between the Synchronisation Contexts